# What is the order output of conv2d in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I wanted to get the values of output tensor in tensorflow. 
the kernel shape of first layer was K[row, col, in_channel, out_channel].
the input image shape is P[batch, row, col, channel]
But I tried to get the first four kernel value, they were `K[0, 0, 0, 0], K[0, 1, 0, 0], K[1, 0, 0, 0], K[1, 1, 0, 0].`

I got the input values were `P[0, 0, 0, 0], P[0, 0, 1, 0], P[0, 1, 0, 0], P[0, 1, 1, 0].`

python code is that "`F = tf.nn.conv2d(P, K, stride=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')"`

Console showed output value `(F[0, 0, 0, 0]) is not K[0, 0, 0, 0] * P[0, 0, 0, 0] + K[0, 1, 0, 0] * P[0, 0, 1, 0] + K[1, 0, 0, 0] * P[0, 1, 0, 0] + K[1, 1, 0, 0] * P[0, 1, 1, 0]`

What is the order of these output feature maps? I had 40 `conv_kernel`,the first output was not computed by the first `conv_kernel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong in your input values.

Remember that conv2d wants  an input tensor of shape `[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]` and a filter / kernel tensor of shape `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`.

In fact, reshaping your data the results are the one expected (please note that conv2d computes the correlation and not the convolution).

```py
import tensorflow as tf

K = tf.get_variable("K", shape=(4,4), initializer=tf.constant_initializer([
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0], 
        [1, 1, 0, 0]
    ]))

K = tf.reshape(K, (4,4,1,1))


P = tf.get_variable("P", shape=(4,4), initializer=tf.constant_initializer([
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0]
    ]))

P = tf.reshape(P, (1,4,4,1))


F = tf.nn.conv2d(P, K, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(F))
```

In this example, I'm computing the correlation between the input P (a batch with 1 element of depth 1) and the filter P (4x4 filter, with input depth 1 and output depth 1).

Comment: I found the key.This problem was caused by the parameter padding = 'SAME'. padding can make input tensor larger than before with zeros around the input tensor if I used SAME.

Comment: SAME padding makes the **output** tensor as big as the input tensor. The input is not touched before the computation. Also, if my answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted.